# using subquery within a where like clause MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Hello everyone I have the following query:

```
update tblAnimal as p 
join tblGrouping as tfs on tfs.tblGroupingId = p.tblGroupingId
join tblShelter as ses on ses.tblShelterId = tfs.tblShelterId
join tblFind as tf on ses.tblFindId = tf.tblFindId
set findColor = 'y'
where p.animalData like (select searchName from tblSearchCriteria where animalId =       p.tblanimalId) 
or    p.history like (select searchName from tblSearchCriteria where animalId =    p.tblanimalId);
```

So I imagine that having this query only returning one column from the subquery is ok but as soon as you start getting multiple values back from that return query we will start getting into trouble.

My question is what is the best way to achieve the above when it is expected that more than one column is returned from the sub query; essentially what i want to do is handle as many searchNames as are in the search criteria table and update the findcolor to 'y' for any of them that match any of the returned search names.

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Before attempting an UPDATE, see if you can write a SELECT that returns the desired result set.

Comment: does searchName contain wildcards like % ?

Comment: no currently it only contains a string which is to be searched for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If searchName contains wilcards like % you could rewrite your query using a JOIN:

```
UPDATE
  tblAnimal as p
  JOIN tblSearchCriteria sc
       ON p.tblanimalId = sc.animalId AND (p.animalData LIKE sc.searchName
                                           OR p.history LIKE sc.searchName)
  JOIN tblGrouping as tfs on tfs.tblGroupingId = p.tblGroupingId
  JOIN tblShelter as ses on ses.tblShelterId = tfs.tblShelterId
  JOIN tblFind as tf on ses.tblFindId = tf.tblFindId
SET
  findColor = 'y'
```

otherwise you could just substitute LIKE with IN.

Comment: thankyou, this turned out to be the best way to reimplement :)